# python regular expression of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have python string

```
wrong_data_type is not one of the allowed values `([one_two, two_three, three_four])`
```

and I have a regexp:

```
\w+ is not one of the allowed values`\(\[\w,+\)\]`
```

However, it is not correct? Any help?

Comment: Not correct. How vague? What is it you wish to accomplish.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The regexp doesn't have a space after `values`, and it doesn't have space after the comma inside `([ ])`

Comment: It also only allows one `\w` inside `([ ])` and multiple `,`, and it requires a comma after the last word inside the brackets.

Comment: And `\)\]` should be `\]\)`. So many simple errors like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp should be

```
\w+ is not one of the allowed values `\(\[(?:\w+, )*\w+\]\)`
```

Fixes:

1. Added space after `values`.
2. `\]\)` at the end instead of `\)\]`.
3. Inside the brackets, need to allow multiple `\w`, so it should be `\w+`.
4. Need to have a space after `,`.
5. Need a group around `\w+,` to match multiple comma-separated words using the `*` quantifier.
6. Then have to match a single last word with no comma after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = re.search(r'\(\[[\w,\s]+\]\)', string).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
\w+ is not one of the allowed values `\(\[[\w,\s]+\]\)`
```

Comment: This will match `([,word,])` at the end. But maybe that's good enough.